# devise custom error styling

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I have the following issue. I'm using devise as an authentication module for my rails 3 application. I have generated devise views to customize them. The issue is with error messages styling. If just put the following

```
<%= devise_error_messages! %>
```

I get the following markup on my page:

```
<div id="error_explanation">
  <h2>3 errors prohibited this user from being saved:</h2>
  <ul>
      <li>Email can't be blank</li><li>Password doesn't match confirmation</li>
      <li>Password is too short (minimum is 6 characters)</li>  
  </ul>
</div>
```

I want to use my own custom markup to display the messages. I couldn't find any way to do this in the devise wiki. How can i do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is actually hard coded in a helper of devise
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/helpers/devise_helper.rb

What you can do is to override or build your own helper in the same fashion.